# Properties and onchange events. Need to find a proper design pattern

Tags: c#, architecture

So I made a socket communication library. And a part of it is `IConnection`

```
public enum ConnectionState
{
    NotConnected, Connecting, Connected, Authenticated, Disconnecting, Disconnected
}

public interface IConnection
{
    ConnectionState State { get; }

    event Action Connected;
    event Action Disconnected;
    event Action Authenticated;
    event Action AuthenticationFailed;

    // this two methods are the core of my question
    void OnAuthenticated();
    void OnAuthenticationFailed();

    bool Send(byte[] data);
    void Connect();
    void Close();
}
```

Of course `IConnection` provides information about connection state and is able to fire `Connected/Disconnected` events as it holds `Socket`. There is no doubt.

Now, users of `IConnection` would also like to know when it becomes authenticated. For example, server might listen to that events, and once connection is authenticated - send client's initial configuration data. Or client might listen to that events and decide to start communication or retry authentication process.

But. The problem is, authentication process exists in the protocol layer. `IConnection` has no idea such layer even exists. Protocol layer actually uses `IConnection` to send serialized to `byte[]` message to the other party.

So, for `IConnection` to be able to change it's state and inform subscribers on auth process i had to implement this two methods

```
void OnAuthenticated();
void OnAuthenticationFailed();
```

Which are, obviously called from protocol layer authentication process code.

I feel like I'm doing something wrong here. And since i work alone, any thoughts will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the core part of the protocol like authentication, keep-alive service and basic message types that will be most likely used everywhere to the Communication assembly.

So now `IConnection` does auth process itself as it is aware of core protocol.